# function pointers between classes

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I am having difficulty getting my head around how to pass a class member function to a subclass (not derived).

My top level class is like this:

```
class CTop
{
public:
    CTop();
    int func1(void);

private:
    CFnList* _funcList;
};

CTop::CTop():
    _funcList(0)
{
    _funcList = new CFnList();
    _funcList->addFnPtrToList(0, &CTop::func1);
}

int CTop::func1(void)
{
    // Does some stuff...
}
```

My function list class is like this:

```
class CFnList
{
public:
    // Public functions
    CFnList();
    void addFnPtrToList(int index, int (*fn)(void));

private:
    // Fn pointer list
    typedef struct
    {
        int index;
        int (*fn) (void);
    }fn_list_t;

    // function pointer list
    QVector<fn_list_t> _fn_list;
};
```

So basically here I have an instance of class CTop and one of its members is a pointer to a class CFnList. CFnList pointer is instantiated in the constructor of CTop. Then I want to pass in a pointer to one of CTop's member functions to CFnList by calling the following line:
"_funcList->addFnPtrToList(0, &CTop::func1);"
I get issue (quite rightly) that addFnPtrToList does not take the parameters (int, (CTop::*)()). So the compiler knows this function is a certain member function and not just a generic (maybe static) function.

Is there a way to pass the a pointer to the member function into the sub-class? In my case I want the sub-class to be able to call this function. I am thinking I probably have to make static member functions or something, but the syntax is eluding me on how to do this.

All help / advise appreciated.
Fodder

Comment: apologies for any slow reply from my side, I have run out of time it is the end of my day :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A declaration in the form:

```
int (*fn)(void)
```

cannot point to a member function.  It can only point to a free function. Philispophically, this is because the calling conventions for member functions are different then that for free functions.  Consider for example the need for a `this` pointer in the context of a member function call.

The syntax for declaring a pointer-to-member-function is like this:

```
int (CTop::*fn)(void)
```

There is an entire section in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) dedicated to member function pointers. Check it out.

Comment: Nice post +1 :) ... in my case I have more then one "CTop" type class that wants to use the CFnList class so telling it specifically the object type is not really an option for me :( FAQ looks a good one, I will certainly read this in the morning!

Comment: since this was the way that worked in the end... forgot to select an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

`CTop::func1` is a member function. `&CTop::func1` is NOT a function pointer, it is a pointer to member (function). Those can not be mixed either in storing or calling. it is not compatible with  `int (*fn)(void)`, as the latter takes no arguments and the former requires an object that is passed as the hidden `this`.

For these reasons you can't have a simple but uniform facility. You either can go with simple function pointers, or pairs of PTM+object pointer, or use wrappers -- handmade or stock like `boost::function` fueled by `boost::bind`.  If you have C++11 or TR1 you can use the std:: equivalents of the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I understand all the options that you have highlighted (+1) expect for "pairs of PTM+object pointer". What is that... its sounds like I can do what I want by also passing the object as well as the member(function)... something like this?

Comment: yes, if you have the pointer-to member pFn and pointer to instance pTop then you can issue `(pTop->*pFn)(ARGS)` making the actual call. It's not hard to store the pairs for a fixed type and signature.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the member function as if it were a regular function. That fails to include the 'this' reference to the class. In order to pass member functions, you have to be able to re-reference it from the original 'this'. Take a look at the following, instead.

```
typedef void (CTop::*OBJFNC)(args);

_funcList = new CFnList();
_funcList->addFnPtrToList(0, this, &CTop::func1);


void addFnPtrToList(int index, CTop* pobj, OBJFNC pfnc)
{ ... Store both ...
}
```

Now elsewhere you can execute it with the following.

```
(pobj->*pfnc)(args);
```

Comment: Thank you for the post. Nice idea +1 :), but I have similar problem as with John's post above. I can't explicitly use the Object type since in my code I have many "CTop" like classes that want to use the CFnList to store pointers to their functions.

Comment: One potential solution would be to have all those classes inherit a common base class and use function overloading. That way the list maintainer could maintain references to CTopInheritedClass ptrs. That's about all I can think of. Either way, you'll have to maintain a pointer to the original 'this' in some form or fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution, it uses a mixture of passing the instance of the object CTop and usage of template class for CFnList:

My top level class is like this (more or less the same except for the declaration of _funcList to includes the class type and to pass in the "this" to the constructor:

```
class CTop
{
public:
    CTop();
    int func1(void);

private:
    CFnList<CTop>* _funcList;
};

CTop::CTop():
    _funcList(0)
{
    _funcList = new CFnList(this);
    _funcList->addFnPtrToList(0, &CTop::func1);
}

int CTop::func1(void)
{
    // Does some stuff...
}
```

My function list class is like this:

```
template<class T>
class CFnList
{
public:
    // Public functions
    CFnList(T *parent);
    void addFnPtrToList(int index, int (T::*fn)(void));

private:
    // Pointer to the parent (or owner is perhaps more correct)
    T* _parent;

    // Fn pointer list
    typedef struct
    {
        int index;
        int (T::*fn) (void);
    }fn_list_t;

    // function pointer list
    QVector<fn_list_t> _fn_list;
};

// Constructor
template <class T>
CFnList<T>::CFnList(T *parent) :
    _parent(parent),
    _fn_list(0)
{
}

// addFnPtrToList:
template <class T>
void CFnList<T>::addFnPtrToList(int index, int (T::*fn)(void))
{
    _fn_list.append((fn_list_t){index, fn});
}
```

So the major changes are:
1. Pass the CTop type in by using changing CFnList into a template.
2. Pass in the instance of the object CTop (so that the pointer to the function can be called) by passing "this" into the constructor and then template class stores it as a pointer to the given template type.... vio-la!...easy :o

Thanks to all who contributed :))

Comment: In fact I will post this issue I have as a new topic because it is not relevant. Then if/when I get the solution working I will update this post. Sorry if that causes anyone confusion/issue!

Comment: Got that template issue resolved now I have posted the complete solution. Thanks to all :)